# Query top level custom post in taxonomy

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy

This is my first post, I'm a bit stuck.

I have a custom post (dan) and taxonomy (dnas), with hierarchical categories.

I want to make a query resulting in posts at toplevel (hoofdcategorie01, hoofdcategorie02).

I have the following code that gives me al the posts.

```
    <?php
        
        
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'dna',
    'orderby'          => 'title',
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'tax' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'dnas',
            'terms' => $term->term_id,
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'include_children' => false,
            //'terms' => 'politics',
        )
    ),
) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
            
        ?>
            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            <?php
            
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
            
            
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Structure]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```php
'tax' => array(
```

There is no `tax` option in `WP_Query` so it's ignored. Did you mean to use `tax_query`?

Comment: Thank you Tom for your reply, I now use tax_query. Seems tax was the old way. :) How to get all posts from top level category, but not the sub categories?

Comment: You're already telling it that, `'include_children' => false,`, see the official docs https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters